# PHP : Force PDF file to download

Tags: php, html

i am trying to download  a .**pdf** file on button submit, following is my code

```
if(mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Brochure Downloaded ', $string)){ 
            $text= 'Your message recieved, We will contact you shrtly '; 
            $file_url = 'http://www.website.com/brochure.pdf'; 
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
                header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
                readfile($file_url); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
    }
```

Now whats happening is that email is sent but files is not downloaded, instead page gets reloading and long characters are printed on the screen ,

Need your help with this please

this is what i get [image]

Comment: Don't you need content-length for this?

Comment: all that i have is here

Comment: Check in your browser's inspector to see if the headers are being set right. Your server could be overriding them.

Comment: where do i check  it in  inspector

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed headers a little bit. I think the proper content type is `application/pdf` andsome of headers are not necessery.

```
if(mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Brochure Downloaded ', $string)){ 
  $text= 'Your message recieved, We will contact you shrtly '; 
  $file_url = 'http://www.website.com/brochure.pdf'; 
  header("Content-type:application/pdf");
  header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='" . basename($file_url) . "'");
  readfile($file_url); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
}
```

You may also add the content length:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_url));
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code, first you need to add content type if you download any type file as like if you want to download image then 
header('Content-Type: image/png'); if pdf then
header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); etc

```
<?php
if (mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Brochure Downloaded ', $string)) {
$text = 'Your message recieved, We will contact you shrtly ';
$file_url = 'http://www.website.com/brochure.pdf';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_url");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
}
?>
```

you may use

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_url));
```

you should use Content-Length if you want someone download a file with another header